# How to create a safe save of an ArrayList and load it also if class is edited?

Tags: java, serialization, save, xml-serialization

I would like to save and load my ArrayList that contains "Book" object.

```
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

I saw many topics about this, and almost all say to use serialization. 
So i done:

**BOOK CLASS**

```
public class Book implements Serializable{
        STUFF
}
```

**MAIN**

```
public static void saveList(String saveName, ArrayList<Book> books) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(saveName);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(books);
        oos.close();
    }

public static ArrayList<Book> loadList(String saveName) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(saveName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    ArrayList<Book> books = (ArrayList<Book>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return books;
}
```

It works but the problem is that if we do a change in the class (for example we add an attribute) it will not load the save anymore.

So i thought to save in a xml file. I saw some topic about write and load in xml file, but almost all have expired links and package removed in latest versions, so they are old soultions that they do not work anymore.

**QUESTION:**
How to create a safe save of my ArrayList that contains object and load it also if i update the Book class? With "safe save", i mean that it will works for long term storage(i readed that serialization is not for long term storage)

I think there is a way, because applications and games read the saves also when they are update. How do they do it?

PS Sorry for my bad english

Comment: instead xml you can use json or yml but be aware that for some changes in the class, loading will fail...

Comment: Up to a certain amount of `Book`s, a shelf (metaphor for *single file*) may suffice (xml, csv, yml, json), but if your *library* keeps growing, you might want to have a library cupboard (metaphor for *database*). Consider using a database for your data…

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of database and manage your schema. Your problem is that you want to change the definition of an object while not updating the existing ones. What should happen when you add a `author` field to a book? Newly created books will hav an author but old ones will not, you need to be prepared for this. This is exactly what schema managers do.